# What are the best practices when joining tables against ids from an external system?

Tags: sql, jdbc

Our group frequently has situations where we need to join our tables against identifiers that come from outside of the database, e.g. downloading data with matching associations found in a public data repository.

I know of basic two approaches. The one we most commonly use involves batching IN clauses. We have a utility for transparently wrapping long IN statements in separate queries when we are joining against >1000 items.

With 5 items and batch limit of 4 the query :

```sql
SELECT foo.id, foo.data FROM foo WHERE foo.id IN ($MANY)
```

becomes:

```sql
SELECT foo.id, foo.data FROM foo WHERE foo.id IN (?,?,?,?)
SELECT foo.id, foo.data FROM foo WHERE foo.id IN (?)
```

This method works but seems quite kludgy.

The alternative sometimes employed involves creating temporary tables, inserting the values, and joining against the normal tables.  This solution seems a bit more standard with respect to the final query as you're simply joining as you would if the data were in your database.  However, the temporary table creation doesn't seem to be something that can done in an ANSI SQL compliant way.

Performance seems to be about equal with the IN method winning favor with few external values as expected.

What is the best practice for solving this problem in an ANSI standard way?

Edit:
With respect to performance measures, we were benchmarking the application code. This included the overhead of inserting into the temp tables. Likewise, for the IN clauses it included the overhead of batching them.

Comment: you should avoid the inner query for performance point of view..Use join if u required from external table or data is from same table then use self join but avoid inner query to gain performance

Comment: Creating a temp table and then populating seems like extra processing.  When you said they are about equal, did you count the time it takes to add all the records?  If so, try it with a couple  thousand records a few times and see if each method still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, and since you are only matching by ID you solution using the IN clause is the best approach, and it is more efficient than a join. A join, even in this simple case were your temp table have only ids, always incurs in a significant overhead over the IN clause. If both options seems to run at the same speed on your system is because you have really small tables in the order of a few thousands ids, but if you increase the number of records in the temp table the IN clause will always win.

My 2 cents